# Get Domain name from FQDN with powershell

Tags: powershell

I had been looking for a short code to do this for a while and finally figured it out myself. Thought I would share it.

```
$FQDN = "madeup.name.domain.co.in"
```

I would need the result as `name.domain.co.in`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An arguably cleaner solution would be

```
$FQDN.Substring($FQDN.IndexOf(".") + 1)
```

This gets the substring of `$FQDN` starting after the first `.`.

Comment: What if my FQDN is something like "madeup.name.madeup.domain.co.in"?

Answer (score 4):

Code:

```
$hostname = $FQDN.Split('.')[0]
$Domain = $FQDN -replace "$hostname.",""
```

`$Domain` will have the result.

Hope this helps

Comment: What if my FQDN is something like `"madeup.name.madeup.domain.co.in"`?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the "registrableDomain" you can use this function:
https://github.com/ili101/PowerShell/blob/master/Get-Domain.ps1

```
Get-Domain madeup.name.madeup.domain.co.in
```

Output: domain.co.in

Comment: By far the best solution. Accepts any URL regardless of subdomain depth.

Comment: I've also changed the variable slightly as I had a few URLs with paths as well. 

Get-Domain ([System.Uri]"https://$URL").Host

Answer (score 2):

**Regex**, to return first segment composed of Letter, digit, '-' and '_'

```
"made-up1.name.madeup.domain.co.in" -replace('(^[\w-_\d]+)\.(.*)','$1')
```

return `made-up1`

DomainName with $2

```
"made-up1.name.madeup.domain.co.in" -replace('(^[\w-_\d]+)\.(.*)','$2')
```

return `name.madeup.domain.co.in`

Comment: can't the hostname be made-up1.name ?

Comment: the hostname must never contain any points, https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1123#page-79

Answer (score 1):

I like this approach from @Rohin Sidharth:

```
$hostname = $FQDN.Split('.')[0]
$Domain = $FQDN -replace "$hostname.",""
```

You can also get the $hostname from the $env variable:

```
$env:computername
```

If you are running on the server in question, then the replace mechanism will provide the domain even if the name of the server has a '.' in it.